# Google Calendar API: Event description and location not working with insert method

Tags: php, api, calendar, google-calendar-api

My application creates Google Calendar Events through the Calendar API. I am able to connect to the API and create events programmatically with PHP.

However, I can't seem to pass in the Location and Description values. The other values, such as Summary, ID, Start, and End are working just fine.

The Location and Description just don't show up in Google Calendar. Why not?

Here is my code:

```
    $event_data = new Google_Service_Calendar_Event(array(
        'summary'     => html_entity_decode($title),
        'id'          => $event_id,
        'location'    => '123 Fake Street',
        'description' => 'This is the event description.',
        'start'       => array(
            'date'      => $start_date,
            'timeZone'  => 'America/Vancouver'
         ),
        'end'         => array(
            'date'      => $end_date,
            'timeZone'  => 'America/Vancouver'
        )
  ));

  try {

   $event = $calendar_service->events->insert($calendar, $event_data);

  } catch ( Exception $e ) {

    echo '<h1>Oh no!</h1>';
    echo '<p>There was an error connecting with Google Calendar:</p>';
    echo '<pre>';
      echo $e->getMessage();
    echo '</pre>';
    die();
  }
```

Thanks!

Comment: I don't see any error with your code as based in this [example](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events/insert#response). Can you please provide the logs?

Comment: Thanks for investigating. Unfortunately the logs show nothing but a few unrelated syntax errors that I've already fixed.

Comment: I had the same issue. Turns out I had an intermediary step where I was formatting my event JSON to match what Google requires where I left out a step. Once I fixed that the location adds just fine.